# Расположить один объект рядом с другим

Tags: c#, unity3d

Необходимо расположить `Объект1` рядом с `Объект2`.

Чтобы найти `d`, мне нужно найти ширину этих объектов, и `distance` будет ровняться сумме половине этих ширин.
Как можно найти ширину этих объектов в системе координат, чтобы в дальнейшем я мог задать `position` у `Объект2`, как `Объект1.position.x + distance`?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Судя по рисунку, предполагается работа в 2d. Все зависит от того, чем вы пользуетесь для отрисовки этих объектов на сцене. В любом случае, центр объекта можно получить с помощью `transform.position`, и все что останется, найти половину ширины каждого объекта. Возможные варианты:

1. `SpriteRenderer` - используйте `SpriteRenderer.bounds`([документация по Bounds](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Bounds.html)), чтобы получить размеры прямоугольника, описывающего ваш объект, а дальше посчитайте половину длины.
2. Unity UI Image - все еще проще чем в первом случае, у каждого объекта на `Canvas` есть компонент `RectTransform`, у которого можно получить [rect](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransform-rect.html) - описывающий его прямоугольник и дальше работать с ним. [Пример](https://answers.unity.com/questions/919516/how-to-get-the-width-height-of-a-recttransform-con.html).

Также, не забудьте что считать расстояние между объектов нужно в одной системе координат (обращая внимание на положение в иерархии и локальные/глобальные координаты). Также для расчета расстояния между двумя точками (центрами объектов) может помочь метод [Vector2.Distance](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2.Distance.html).

Comment: `SpriteRenderer` то, что мне было нужно. Спасибо!